# php file upload with validation type

Tags: php, html, file-upload

In php I have my code for uploading files is like this

```
 $image_name= $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
  $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  $extension = end($temp);
  if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
  && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
      echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else {
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $tmpName.$image_name);
    }
  }
```

Now this code is working fine when I am doing upload. But it doesn't work with the filetype validation. I have used 
  `$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png"); to use only these types of file to upload. But this one is uploading any files type. So can someone kindly tell me where is the wrong part here. I want to upload only` "gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png" files only. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciale. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had a problem with file types before and I couldn't resolve it so I decided to go on with something else.
This was one of my ways to check if the files being uploaded were "images" way before. I don't think a great way to check if a file is actually an image, but it actually worked for me and I couldn't think of anything else by the time.

```
<?php
    if(isAnImage($routetoyourfile)) {
        //Move the file
    } else {
        //Delete it
    }
    function isAnImage($fileroute) {
        $ext = pathinfo($fileroute, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if($ext != "jpg" && $ext != "jpeg" && $ext != "png" && $ext != "JPG" && $ext != "PNG" && $ext != "JPEG") {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
?>
```